# No 'apply now' button for careers, using iPad Air/iOS 7.0.6

Tags: bug, status-deferred, jobs, ipad, mobile-safari

Browsing for (junior) JavaScript jobs on [careers](http://careers.stackexchange.com) (hint, hint…) I found a few that I'd like to apply to, but browsing the job page there seems to be no way to actually apply (for clarity this applies to iPad Air/iOS 7.0.6) for positions, due to the lack of an 'apply now' button:

iPad Air/iOS 7.0.6:

[image]

iPhone 4s/iOS 7.0.6:

[image]

Nexus 7 (original model, Android KitKat):

[image]

Link to actual job page (though it's true of *all* job pages that I've browsed on iPad): http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/45651/javascript-developer-dotmailer?a=TFVhlEhW&searchTerm=JavaScript

Incidentally, I have previously flagged this problem via the in-page 'report a problem' facility (around, or slightly before, 17/02/2014) and received this response:

> Hi David,
>
> Thanks for showing your interest in this position:
>   http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/48534<sup>**1**</sup>
>
> You should be able to see the "apply now" button at the bottom of this job listing.
>   Can you try a different browser if you aren't able to see that?
>
> Cheers,
>   (Name removed, since I don't think it's fair to potentially embarrass someone)

---

**1:** Note that this is an entirely different job, though it shows the same behaviour.

Comment: I don't have an iPhone (more recent than iPhone 3), so if someone could confirm the presence, or absence, of the 'apply now' button that'd be appreciated.

Comment: iPhone 4S, 7.0.6 [shows the "apply now" button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ228.jpg) (although incidentally, there is no "apply now" in the mobile view). FWIW, the "apply now" button should appear higher up the page than your first screenshot shows, making it moot.

Comment: I'm think has to with the way iOS handles documents. There's no good way to upload a resume. Android is no issue. I'll confirm if this is by design. Or I know we've had some safari styling issues in the past.

Comment: @Matt: thanks! I hadn't noticed that >.< (edited)

Comment: @Juice: thank you (though the previous response seems to imply that it's not by-design, though there's a chance I wasn't clear enough in my reporting of the problem).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official answer incoming:

We don't really support applying for listing on mobile devices (phones and tablets). On phones, the site should default to the mobile theme (which hides all application functionality) and this illustrates a reason why we should do so on tablets as well.

Currently applying form a mobile device is in the "if it works, it works, but we don't explicitly support it" realm.

I am not a dev, but I could have sworn part of that reason was the way iOS handles documents. Android should fare better but I don't have a device I can test it with.

So in regards to your issue, this may be a bug in the classic sense, but it's not a bug we're prepared to spend time fixing since we don't support mobile application anyway.

I've marked it as status-deferred for now. While we have no immediate plans to allow mobile applications, we'll probably have to revisit this issue on the future since we've started releasing our own SE mobile apps.

Comment: While I won't down vote the answer, I can't say this is a position I'm happy with; Stack Exchange has already [acknowledged their faults as regards the early dismissal of mobile](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/), further dismissal of the mobile platform further compounds that error. Especially given that mobile usage is (anecdotally) increasing faster than desktop usage, or perhaps in the face of desktop...uh, diminishment? Still, if that's the official verdict it might be worth making that explicit in the site itself if a mobile platform is detected.

Comment: I agree. I'm going to try to get mobile platforms to default to the mobile theme for now. It's something we're going to have to do, but we're in a situation where the things we want to do outweigh the number of developers we employ. If you know anybody please share http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/34229/full-stack-web-developer-stack-exchange?a=FKfeWpH2&searchTerm=Stack%20exchange we're always hiring.

Comment: If it's front-end, remote-working JavaScript/HTML/CSS devs you're looking for, I believe I might know [someone](http://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas)… (*hint*, **hint**) ;) (albeit entirely self-taught hobbyist thus far, sigh)

Comment: @DavidThomas Feel free to apply. Self taught is welcome here. But be prepared to impress during interviews. I think devs even have to interview with Joel Spolsky at some point.