# Careers site missing "Apply Now" on iPad

Tags: bug, jobs, ipad

I was browsing through job postings and noticed the "Apply Now" button was nowhere to be found.  I tried Mobile and Desktop versions, but when I checked it out this morning on my Mac everything was fine. I suspect a media query or other CSS style is hiding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because we don't currently support applying to listing on mobile devices. While I agree this is something we will look at in the future, less than 10% of our traffic on Careers is mobile so it's not a priority at the moment.

Comment: Can you please close this as dupe of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223943/no-apply-now-button-for-careers-using-ipad-air-ios-7-0-6?rq=1), and update your answer there if something changed? Having the same bug report twice with two different answers is... confusing.